# Extracting in Bash Script

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have a file with values like this:

31.13.77.12:443         TIME_WAIT
31.13.77.12:443         ESTABLISHED
31.13.77.36:443         ESTABLISHED
31.13.77.29:443         ESTABLISHED
31.13.77.12:443         TIME_WAIT

I want the output in a file as:

IP_ADDR             Port        Status                    Count
31.13.77.12     443       TIME_WAIT                2
31.13.77.12     443       ESTABLISHED         1
31.13.77.36     443      ESTABLISHED         1
31.13.77.29     443      ESTABLISHED         1

All the fields are tab separated. I am able to extract the ip & port but i am not aware of how to compare two columns and get the count.

Comment: awk -F"\t" '!seen[$1, $2]++' file.txt is giving me the unique values based on two columns but i am not bale to count it

Comment: You can use `uniq -c` to count unique lines (the lines must be sorted beforehand).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
netstat -n | awk  '$1=="tcp"{print $5,$6}' OFS="\t\t" >output.txt  
sort output.txt | uniq --count >output1.txt  
echo -e "Count"  "IP" '\t\t' "Port" '\t' "State"  >final.txt  
sed 's/\:/\t/' output1.txt >> final.txt
```

Comment: You might add some explanation to this answer as well explaining what this is doing exactly.